# How do I plot the data distribution and theoretical density?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

First of, I'm not sure if this is a valid approach statistics-wise, but hear me out.

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(counts = c(3, 568, 147, 497, 3, 10, 929, 283, 
10, 1, 8, 650, 1, 278, 198, 14, 495, 521, 2, 509, 169, 4, 2, 
411, 266, 1, 122, 169, 22, 90, 740, 2, 0, 1016, 2, 294, 871, 
2, 308, 486, 124, 627, 374, 2, 2, 1, 812, 0, 191, 9, 4, 12, 28, 
698, 448, 12, 183, 11, 8, 561, 5, 386, 2, 443, 488, 343, 2, 28, 
8, 209, 269, 653, 2, 633, 871, 54, 4, 275, 376, 0, 0, 481, 2, 
2, 3, 12, 439, 2, 513, 7, 375, 437, 675, 0, 374, 0, 172, 1, 369, 
146, 7, 1, 20, 0, 923, 936, 808, 517, 150, 2, 0, 2, 109, 5, 5, 
634, 13, 7, 29, 6, 469, 566, 16, 704, 3, 389, 744, 0, 219, 625, 
0, 6, 360, 467, 409, 212, 605, 2, 206, 225, 2, 25, 7, 20, 1082, 
6, 878, 90, 517, 2, 2, 323, 163, 3, 9, 203, 0, 2, 7, 648, 137, 
183, 7, 0, 464, 3, 576, 38, 8, 582, 128, 677, 546, 1, 137, 380, 
314, 469, 3, 352, 2, 702, 0, 2, 372, 2, 126, 3, 6, 516, 1, 2, 
1, 399, 431, 314, 467, 7, 341, 117, 915, 471, 287, 59, 170, 279, 
457, 206, 752, 4, 14, 6, 650, 13, 1, 403, 415, 7, 8, 5, 90, 884, 
366, 240, 1, 8, 5, 7, 4, 379, 870, 523, 12, 740, 3, 2, 1, 5, 
4, 2, 99, 1, 515, 80, 9, 210, 62, 384, 2, 185, 27, 626, 266, 
846, 540, 261, 118, 419, 125, 147, 350, 553, 1, 5, 480, 295, 
416, 105, 701, 15, 343, 415, 711, 74, 548, 17, 589, 158, 580, 
191, 15, 44, 595, 9, 221, 12, 1, 553, 2, 482, 10, 4, 384, 26, 
265, 593, 37, 1, 50, 461, 799, 7, 502, 70, 350, 1100, 0, 3, 2, 
1, 195, 495, 2, 1, 5, 7, 458, 198, 563, 199, 120, 14, 7, 0, 8, 
667, 204, 10, 5, 376, 2, 1, 135, 27, 703, 192, 956, 210, 5, 1, 
6, 9, 2, 3, 1, 10, 516, 2, 8, 4, 3, 165, 70, 217, 701, 483, 8, 
2, 520, 2, 71, 263, 568, 637, 485, 3, 138, 6, 780, 9, 489, 11, 
2, 494, 7, 1, 221, 98, 534, 5, 3, 9, 70, 4, 0, 8, 761, 2, 4, 
821, 91, 1, 274, 125, 8, 5, 101, 3, 467, 0, 0, 9, 241, 2, 528, 
411, 2, 187, 528, 460, 118, 6, 522, 267, 10, 244, 2, 13, 218, 
5, 85, 655, 3, 764, 2, 430, 431, 5, 5, 445, 287, 0, 109, 7, 3, 
489, 535), cluster = structure(c(8L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 
9L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
6L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
8L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 
6L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 
8L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 
4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 
2L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
3L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 
6L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 
4L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 
6L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 
3L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
4L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 
9L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 
8L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 
8L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 
5L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("GATCGCGGTTATCGGT", 
"GGCTGGTAGAGGTTAT", "ACAGCTACAGATCGGA", "CAACTAGCAGCTCGAC", "TCTCATACATCGATGT", 
"AGCATACTCTCCCTGA", "CAACCTCCAGTACACT", "TCGGGACAGGATGTAT", "TCTCTAATCAGAGCTT", 
"CAGAATCTCCGGCACA", "GTTAAGCTCGAATGGG", "TACTTACAGTTGTCGT", "CTAAGACTCTTCTGGC", 
"GTAGGCCCACTGTCGG", "CGATGGCCAAACAACA", "GACGGCTGTGATGTCT", "TGGTTCCTCAACACTG", 
"CCTAGCTGTTACGGAG", "CAGCCGAAGACTACAA", "TGACAACTCTCTGCTG", "GTTCATTTCCCACTTG", 
"GCATGATAGGTGTTAA", "TTCTCAATCTTTCCTC", "GCACATATCTCTAAGG", "TTGTAGGTCCGTCATC", 
"TCATTACGTCTCAACA", "AGCTCCTTCACGCGGT", "ACTGATGAGATACACA", "CAACTAGAGTACGACG", 
"CAAGTTGGTTTAGGAA", "TGAGCATTCACGAAGG", "CCATTCGCAGAGTGTG", "CTACACCGTAAGTGGC", 
"CGAGCACCATTAGCCA", "CGTTCTGCATCCAACA", "GGCTCGAGTCCTCTTG", "GCCTCTACATGGTCTA", 
"GCATACAGTAGCGTGA", "GAACGGAGTCAACATC", "AGTCTTTAGATCCCGC", "AGACGTTAGTCTTGCA", 
"GGGTCTGTCGTAGGAG", "AAGGTTCTCTTGAGAC", "GTGAAGGTCACATGCA", "TAAACCGAGAGTCGGT", 
"TAGTTGGAGGCCCTCA", "TAGTGGTAGTCTCCTC", "TTAGGCAGTTGCTCCT", "CGGTTAAGTTCCTCCA", 
"TTATGCTTCTGTGCAA", "ATCCACCCACATTCGA", "TGCACCTCAGAGTGTG", "GGGTTGCCACTGCCAG", 
"AGTCTTTCATCGGTTA", "AGTGAGGTCGATGAGG", "GCGCAGTGTCGAATCT", "CAGCTGGGTAATCACC", 
"GTGAAGGGTTCCGTCT", "TACCTATGTCACTGGC", "GCAGCCAGTAGTACCT", "CATGCCTCATGCCCGA", 
"GATCAGTTCCGTCATC", "ACGTCAAAGTCGCCGT", "GCTTGAATCATCGGAT", "AAGTCTGCACATGGGA", 
"GTTCGGGGTTCACGGC", "GTGTTAGCATTCGACA", "ATAGACCAGGACAGAA", "TAGAGCTGTGAGGGAG", 
"TCAGATGCAGCGTAAG", "ATTATCCTCATACGGT", "TGAGCCGTCCCGGATG", "AGATTGCGTCTACCTC", 
"GCGCAGTGTCAAAGAT", "TGAGGGAAGAACAACT", "GACTAACTCACAGGCC", "CCTTCGAAGGGAAACA", 
"CGTGAGCAGTTTGCGT", "CGTCTACTCTTGGGTA", "GGTGCGTCATACTCTT", "TCAATCTGTCTTGCGG", 
"TGAGAGGAGGGTCGAT", "TAGAGCTTCCCGACTT", "TGTGGTAAGAATGTGT", "ACACCCTCAACACCTA", 
"AGTCTTTCACATTAGC", "TGAAAGAAGCGTAATA", "TGCACCTCACAACGTT", "AATCGGTAGCTCTCGG", 
"CGAGCCAGTAGTAGTA", "TCCACACAGAAGGACA", "AGGGAGTAGATGTAAC", "GAGTCCGAGCTCCTCT", 
"GCTTCCACAGACAAAT", "GCCTCTAGTTAAGACA", "CGCTGGAGTCACTTCC", "CGTGTAACATGGGAAC", 
"CTAACTTAGCGATATA", "TCAGGTAAGGGTTCCC", "TTAGTTCTCGAGAACG", "CAGCTAACAAACTGCT", 
"TAAGAGAGTCTTGTCC", "GTGTGCGTCCGTTGTC", "TCGAGGCGTCTTGTCC", "GACAGAGTCAAAGACA", 
"TGATTTCGTCACACGC", "CGCGGTACACTTCTGC", "CTAGCCTTCCGTCAAA", "CTACACCCAAGAAAGG", 
"GTGTGCGGTCAATACC", "CCATTCGAGCACAGGT", "CGAACATAGCAGATCG", "CGATGGCAGTACGATA", 
"AAATGCCAGCAACGGT", "AGGTCCGCACGAAGCA", "AGTGGGACAAGTTGTC", "TTATGCTAGTACGACG", 
"CTGCGGATCCATGAAC", "ACTTGTTCAAATTGCC", "GTGCTTCCAGGAATCG", "GCTTCCAGTGGTAACG", 
"ACGCCGATCTTTCCTC", "GCTGGGTCAACAACCT", "CATGGCGGTCCAGTGC", "CGGACACAGCTGTTCA", 
"ACGCAGCAGCTACCGC", "CAAGGCCTCATAACCG", "TGAGCATCAGCCTTTC", "ATCATGGTCGCTTAGA", 
"TGCGGGTGTTGTACAC", "GAATGAAGTCAGTGGA", "TGTGGTACATAAAGGT", "TTTATGCTCACCATAG", 
"CGACTTCAGGATCGCA", "GTGCGGTGTAGAGCTG", "TGCTACCAGAGGACGG", "CGTTCTGTCCTAGGGC", 
"GAAACTCGTTCCCGAG", "CATCAAGCAATTGCTG", "GGGTTGCTCCGTAGTA", "CTGCGGATCCGCATCT", 
"GAAGCAGGTAGCGCAA", "TGTATTCAGATAGGAG", "TCAACGACAAGACGTG", "GCCAAATTCGAGGTAG", 
"TTAGTTCCATCCGCGA", "TTGGCAAGTTCCATGA", "GTTCGGGGTACCGTTA", "CCCAATCAGTTGTCGT", 
"CGATGTATCGATGAGG", "CTCGGGACATATACCG", "TCGAGGCTCTTAGCCC", "TAAGCGTTCACGGTTA", 
"CTTGGCTAGTGCTGCC", "AGTGGGACAGCTGCAC", "TTGCGTCAGTAGATGT", "CTGCGGACAGCTCCGA", 
"TGCGTGGCACATTTCT", "CATGGCGAGGCTATCT", "GGGATGACATCTCCCA", "GACCTGGGTCTCTTAT", 
"CAGCTGGCAAGAAGAG", "TAGCCGGAGCAGGTCA", "CAGCTAATCACAGTAC", "TATTACCTCCTTGCCA", 
"CTCGTCACATTCTCAT", "TCAACGATCTTTAGTC", "CTGAAGTCACTCAGGC", "TCAGCTCAGTTGTCGT", 
"CATTATCGTAAGTTCC", "GTGGGTCGTAGCGCAA", "CATGACAGTCTAACGT", "CAGTCCTAGGACACCA", 
"CTCAGAAGTCGAATCT", "GGGTCTGTCCACGAAT", "GCTGCGAAGCCACGTC", "GAATGAAGTGAGTATA", 
"TGCTGCTCATGCTGGC", "GCTTGAAGTTGGTAAA", "GATGCTAGTGCTTCTC", "GTACTCCCACTGCCAG", 
"AGCAGCCCAAGTCTGT", "GAAGCAGGTTAAGGGC", "ACCTTTACAGGGTACA", "ACTGTCCAGTATTGGA", 
"ACTTGTTAGAGTCTGG", "CGGAGTCAGCTAGTTC", "CCGTGGATCGACCAGC", "CAGCTGGCATACGCTA", 
"CTGCTGTTCATTGCCC", "GGGTTGCTCATCATTC", "GCATGCGGTTTAGGAA", "ATCACGAGTGGGTCAA", 
"ACATACGCACGGTAGA", "CCTAAAGTCCGTAGTA", "CAACCTCGTAGCAAAT", "AAGGTTCGTAAGGGAA", 
"CGGACTGTCGGTGTTA", "GATCGATCAGCTGGCT", "GCGCAACAGCTATGCT", "GCAAACTTCCGCAGTG", 
"TTGAACGAGAGGTAGA", "TAAGTGCTCGCCAGCA", "GTGCATAAGAAACGAG", "GCAATCAGTACGAAAT", 
"TACACGAAGTCGAGTG", "AGAGCTTCACTTGGAT", "GACGGCTCACATCTTT", "TATCTCACACTGCCAG", 
"GCACATATCTCCAACC", "TGCCCTATCGGATGTT", "GATGCTAGTAGGGACT", "TGTGTTTGTCGCCATG", 
"ACCAGTATCAGTTGAC", "TGGTTCCTCCGGGTGT", "CTAGCCTCATACAGCT", "GCGAGAAGTTCACCTC", 
"GGAAAGCAGGATGTAT", "CATGCCTGTCGAGTTT", "ACAGCCGTCCACGTTC", "TTTCCTCGTCTCCATC", 
"GCTTCCAGTGAAGGCT", "AGGGAGTTCGTTACGA", "AGATCTGTCTCGTATT", "TGTTCCGCATCCCACT", 
"TGATTTCGTTACGACT", "CAGCCGAAGTCCGGTC", "GCATACATCCCAACGG", "TCTGAGATCCGCATAA", 
"TTGGCAACATGCCACG", "GGTGAAGAGCTGATAA", "TCGGGACCACTGTTAG", "TCAGATGGTCTTGTCC", 
"GGACAAGCACCGCTAG", "CAGATCATCCGTAGGC", "CTCACACGTTCCGGCA", "CATCAAGGTGCAGACA", 
"TAGCCGGGTTAAGATG", "CCATGTCTCGATCCCT", "ATTATCCCAGCCAATT", "GCCTCTAGTTGAGGTG", 
"CAAGAAAAGCTGTCTA", "CGTTGGGTCACCAGGC", "CGTAGCGTCTTGAGAC", "AACGTTGGTTGCTCCT", 
"CATCCACGTGAGTATA", "TGAGGGACAATGGACG", "CCAGCGAAGCTATGCT", "CGTTGGGTCACGGTTA", 
"ACTATCTGTAGCGTAG", "ATTTCTGCATGGTCAT", "TACGGATGTCCTGCTT", "TGGTTCCCAGACGTAG", 
"GCAAACTGTAGCGTGA", "CCACGGAGTAACGACG", "GGCCGATAGCGTTGCC", "GGTGCGTAGAAACCAT", 
"ACGATACGTTCTGAAC", "GACACGCTCCAAACTG", "GCCTCTAGTTCAGTAC", "TCGAGGCGTGAGTATA", 
"TACTCGCCAGGATTGG", "GGGAATGTCTTCATGT", "ACTTTCATCTATCCCG", "GTGCATAGTAAACCTC", 
"AAGTCTGCATTCTCAT", "TCGGTAATCCACGCAG", "CAGCATAAGCCGTCGT", "GCTGGGTCACTAAGTC", 
"CTTACCGGTCTCATCC", "CGTCAGGCAAAGTCAA", "ACGGAGATCCAAACTG", "GCATACAAGTAGCGGT", 
"GACTGCGCAGAAGCAC", "ACTGAGTAGTGATCGG", "GAATGAATCGCGGATC", "CAAGTTGGTACTCGCG", 
"GATGCTAAGACTAGAT", "GATGCTATCAAACCAC", "AAATGCCTCTTTACAC", "GTAGTCATCTGGTGTA", 
"TCACGAACAAGTTGTC", "TTGCCGTTCTAACGGT", "CGGACTGAGTCCGTAT", "TGGACGCAGGAGTAGA", 
"TACCTTAGTACAGCAG", "TCGCGAGAGGTGCAAC", "ACTGAACAGGTGGGTT", "GCACATATCCACGTTC", 
"AGTGAGGTCGTCCAGG", "GGGTTGCTCTACTCAT", "CTCAGAAAGTGAACAT", "CTGTGCTTCAACGGCC", 
"ACGGCCACACCTTGTC", "TCTGAGACAAGAAAGG", "CACAGGCAGTACACCT", "TCGGTAAAGATCCCGC", 
"TCATTACCATCACGTA", "ACATCAGGTGATGTCT", "GACAGAGTCAGCTTAG", "CTACCCACAAACCTAC", 
"TTCTTAGTCTCTAGGA", "AAGCCGCGTTATCCGA", "GTACGTAAGATGCCAG", "TTCGGTCGTCTCGTTC", 
"GTACGTATCCAATGGT", "TTATGCTAGACGACGT", "CAGAATCTCACTCTTA", "ATTCTACTCGTTTAGG", 
"GCAAACTGTGGGTCAA", "GGGTCTGTCTGATACG", "TTTGTCATCCTAAGTG", "GCTGCGAGTCGAGTTT", 
"GAATAAGAGCGTGTCC", "TCTCTAACACGGTAGA", "GAATAAGCAAGTCTAC", "AACTTTCCAATGTAAG", 
"TAGACCATCCTAGGGC", "TGACTTTCAAGTACCT", "AAAGCAAGTGATAAAC", "GGATTACGTCTTCAAG", 
"AGAGCTTGTAGAGTGC", "GCTGCTTGTGAGGGTT", "GGCAATTAGCACCGTC", "TCAGGATGTAGCGTAG", 
"ACGAGCCGTTCCACTC", "GAACGGAAGAGACGAA", "TACGGATGTCGGGTCT", "AGTTGGTTCCCGACTT", 
"AGCCTAATCGTTTGCC", "CAGTCCTAGTGTGGCA", "CTGCGGAAGAGTAAGG", "CGAGCACCACCACGTG", 
"TTAACTCCATCAGTCA", "TTGCCGTCAAAGTCAA", "GTACTCCTCGGATGGA", "AATCCAGTCCGGGTGT", 
"ATCTGCCGTCCGTGAC", "TACGGATCAATCCAAC", "TGGCTGGGTTGATTGC", "CATCAAGGTCGCATCG", 
"AGCTCCTCAGCTTCGG", "CACACAATCAACACAC", "TTCTACAAGCTGAAAT", "GACTGCGGTCAGCTAT", 
"TACAGTGCACATCCAA", "GACGTGCGTGCAGACA", "GGACAAGTCTGCAGTA", "TAGGCATGTCAGTGGA", 
"CTTACCGTCGTAGGTT", "CGAGCACAGACAATAC", "AGGTCATCAGTATAAG", "TGTTCCGTCTGCGTAA", 
"TCAGCAACATTCTCAT", "GTACTTTGTTCAGACT", "TTGAACGCACCCATTC", "CAAGTTGGTAAGTGGC", 
"CAAGTTGAGTACGCGA", "CCTCTGAGTGTGCGTC", "CCAGCGATCCAAGTAC", "ACTGATGGTAAAGGAG", 
"CTTAACTAGCTAGTCT", "ACACCAAAGTGGTCCC", "ACTGAACGTCTACCTC", "AGTGGGAAGCGGATCA", 
"GTTACAGCATAGTAAG", "CAAGGCCAGAGGTTAT", "TTTCCTCTCTACCAGA", "CTGTGCTGTCATCGGC", 
"CCTATTATCCTTGCCA", "TCAGGTAGTAGCTGCC", "TTCTACACATTCGACA", "TGTGGTACATCACAAC", 
"CAGCGACGTACCGCTG", "AGTTGGTTCACTTCAT", "TACTTGTAGCGTAATA", "TTAGTTCGTGTGCCTG", 
"TGTTCCGTCACCTCGT", "AACTGGTAGAGGTTGC", "CACATAGTCAGCGATT", "CTGCTGTGTGACGGTA", 
"ACATACGCAATAACGA", "TAGTGGTCACGTTGGC", "CTGAAACTCGCCTGAG", "ACTTACTAGTAGGTGC", 
"TCTGAGAAGGGTTCCC", "GTTTCTAGTGCACCAC", "TCAGCTCAGCGATCCC", "AACGTTGCAAGGTGTG", 
"GAATGAACAAAGTCAA", "AAACGGGTCTTGAGGT", "CCTTTCTTCAGGCAAG", "GGACAAGAGCTAAGAT", 
"GGCTGGTTCTTGCATT", "TGCGCAGAGCCAGTAG", "CCACTACGTGTTGGGA", "TCAGGTAAGACGCTTT", 
"CCACCTACATGTCTCC", "GAACATCTCAGAGCTT", "AGTCTTTTCCAAGCCG", "GATCGCGAGCTATGCT", 
"AACGTTGCAGCGAACA", "AACTGGTTCGTCCGTT", "TTGCCGTGTTATGCGT", "TCAATCTTCCAACCAA", 
"GAGTCCGTCGGAAACG", "AACACGTGTCGCTTCT", "TGGACGCAGAAGATTC", "GCTTCCATCTGTCAAG", 
"GGGCACTTCGATAGAA", "TGACTTTGTTCAGACT", "GTGCGGTAGACACTAA", "CAGCATATCTACTATC", 
"TTGGCAATCGGGAGTA", "CAGAGAGTCTGTCCGT", "AGAGCTTAGCCCAGCT", "TGGTTCCGTCTAACGT", 
"GCGGGTTTCTATCCCG", "TCACAAGAGCGTGAGT", "TCCCGATAGATAGGAG", "TCTCTAATCGTATCAG", 
"CACCACTAGGGATGGG", "TAGACCAGTTCTGGTA", "TCAGCTCGTTAGATGA", "TACGGATTCTAGAGTC", 
"GTCATTTAGTGGTAGC", "GTACTCCTCTGGCGTG", "AATCCAGCAGGAACGT", "AGCAGCCGTGCAGGTA", 
"GAAATGATCAGGTAAA", "CCATGTCGTGGTACAG", "CACCTTGAGCGCCTCA", "TTAGTTCAGTTCGCGC", 
"GTGTTAGCAGGAATGC", "GACTAACAGATGCGAC", "TTGGCAACACTAGTAC", "GCTGCGAGTTGTGGCC"
))
```

I want to fit different kind of GLMs to compare how well they fit the data like so:

```
fit_poisson_CD8_all_groups <- glm(counts~1, data = df_CD8)
summary(fit_poisson_CD8_all_groups)
```

In the next step I want to compare how theoretical density(with the fitted intercept) matches the shape of the data:

```
pred_density_pois <- dpois(df_CD8$counts, lambda=fit_poisson_CD8_all_groups$coefficients[1])

df_CD8 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = counts, color='red')) +
    geom_histogram(fill = "white") +
    geom_line(aes(x = counts, y = pred_density_pois), color= 'blue')
```

However, histogram and line are on different scales(duh) and "theoretical" line is not visible. How do I scale two plots to be comparable?

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just compare a density plot to the theoretical value:

```r
df_CD8 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = counts)) +
    geom_density( aes(fill = "Actual density"), color = "red") +
    geom_line(aes(x = counts, y = pred_density_pois, 
                  color= "Poisson with same mean")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "white", name = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = "blue", name = "")
```

[image]

Or get the histogram like this:

```r
df_CD8 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = counts)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count../nrow(df_CD8)/10, fill = "Actual density"),
                   binwidth = 10, color = "red") +
    geom_line(aes(x = counts, y = pred_density_pois, 
                  color= "Poisson with same mean")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "white", name = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = "blue", name = "") +
  labs(y = "Density")
```

[image]